# Get User Role in Parse

Tags: mongodb-query, parse-server

I'm trying to get a user roles on login with in a cloud function. I know its a very simple task, but I am unable to solve it. I tried the way docs have mentioned using `innerQuery` that doesn't seem to work either. Since I'm relatively new, I am sure I'm making a silly mistake. Can you please point out my mistake?

My function looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('login', async (req, res) => {
    // TODO: put a validation layer here
    // if (!req.user) res.error('user undefined');

    if (!req.params.email || !req.params.password) res.error('email/password is required');
    const userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    const roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    try {
        const user = await Parse.User.logIn(req.params.email, req.params.password);
        const userRoleQuery = user.relation(Parse.Role).query();

        const role = await userRoleQuery.find();

        res.success(role);
    } catch (error) {
        res.error(error);
    }
});
```

attached is my `_Join:users_Role` table as well:
I am querying on the second user.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to check if a user is assign to specific role? Because in parse-server you cannot get all user roles. parse-server work with ACL's in order to grant/block access to one or more users.

Comment: can you please elaborate what exactly do you mean when you say can not get all user roles?

Comment: What I am saying is that you can check if a specific user is assign to one of more roles but there is no "relationship" between users and roles in parse-server. In the Role collection you have a relationship to Users and from there you can know which roles assigned to which users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also can do it like:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('getRole', async (request) => {
  const query = await new Parse.Query(Parse.Role).equalTo('users', request.user).find()
  return query
})
```

**Or you can use it in your client just with the second row**

Comment: This just made my day, my week and possibly my month :)

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit, I am pretty bad at picking up things quickly.

Turns out to be simpler than I assumed.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('login', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.params.email || !req.params.password) res.error('email/password is required');
    const userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    const roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    try {
        const user = await Parse.User.logIn(req.params.email, req.params.password);
        const userRoleQuery = user.relation(Parse.Role).query();

        const role = await userRoleQuery.find();

        res.success(role);
    } catch (error) {
        res.error(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Swift 5.x:

```swift
func checkIfUserIsLogged() async -> String? {
    guard let currentUser = PFUser.current() else {
        return nil
    }

    let query = PFRole.query()
    let result = try? await query?.whereKey("users", equalTo: currentUser.self).firstObjectInBackground()

    let roleName = result?["name"] as? String

    return roleName
}
```

Usage:

```swift
Task {
    let roleName = await self.checkIfUserIsLogged()
    print(roleName)
}
```